# Grant admin consent failed for office 365 api permissions

Tags: azure-ad-b2b, azure-ad-powershell-v2

My requirement is creating an application in Azure AD and grant Application permissions for that application and grant admin consent for those permissions.

I created an Azure Application through Azure Portal and grant few permissions:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GXAe.png)

I tried to grant admin consent but I get the below error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Biddo.png)

Please help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure to enable **Audit Logs in Office365** to grant admin consent for Office 365 Management API permissions.

Make sure to enable **Audit logs** for Office365 by following this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/turn-audit-log-search-on-or-off?view=o365-worldwide#verify-the-auditing-status-for-your-organization).

```
Set-AdminAuditLogConfig -UnifiedAuditLogIngestionEnabled $true
```

*After enabling you will be able to grant admin consent for Office 365 Management API permissions successfully.*